# AND/OR Operator Precedence in Google Search

Tags: php, operators

I need to do an advanced Google search, using their SiteSearch API. I'm currently using a string of the following format that is sent via curl to my search engine:

```
$search_url = "http://www.google.com/search?start=0&num=20&as_qdr=" . $as_qdr . "&q=" . $q . "&sort=date&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=" . $cx;
```

The problem is that my query needs to be of the form:

("MY SENTENCE" AND "JOHN DOE") OR "MIKE TYSON"

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find anything in Google Documentations to replace the usual sql parenthesis. I have tried using the parenthesis itself but although most results seem accurate, some of the results do not really match the query. For example, they contain "MY SENTENCE" and "MIKE TYSON", but not JOHN DOE.

Is it even possible to do such complicated queries in Google?

**Edit:**
I just forgot to mention that I tried the parenthesis directly on google.com (not using the API), for my testing.

Comment: Have you seen the article [Crafting Your Query](http://www.googleguide.com/crafting_queries.html)?

Comment: Nop! Great site I am reading through it right now, I hope I find an answer though? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Google Guide](http://www.googleguide.com) website, which *is not* affiliated with Google, you can use a mix of both, the `OR` operator (alternatively `|`) and the double quotes `"` as a group compound, to achieve what you wanted, it's all described in [this article](http://www.googleguide.com/or_operator.html).
Further the whole [Crafting Your Query](http://www.googleguide.com/crafting_queries.html) article is also interesting to learn how to get the most of Google's possibilities when using their search.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply (again). I have already read through the Google Guide you posted, and it was very useful. However, the use of the OR operator and the double quotes do not achieve what I want. The problem that I posted is about operator precedence. So basically, I am looking for ("A B" AND "B C") OR E. I already know about the double quotes and OR. My question is what replaces the parenthesis?

Comment: How about `"MY SENTENCE" +"JOHN DOE" OR "MIKE TYSON"`? The brackets or parenthesis shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Still getting same issue, but since most results are good ones and there is no official documentation on "operator precedence", I think my best bets are either to accept the results as they are (since most seem relevant), or split my query into two separate queries. thanks a lot, especially for the website!

Answer (score 0):

You can't force this order of operations on Google: *("MY SENTENCE" AND "JOHN DOE") OR "MIKE TYSON".* 
Google does not have an AND operator.
Or is always first; parentheses do not matter.